# How can i add a speed and power control to the script to move the space ship forward?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is working like i wanted i can rotate the space ship using the arrow keys.

But what it does for now when running the game the ship is automatic lift up.
What i want to add is two things:

1. Make the ship start on ground on idle state and only when pressing a key the ship will start lift up or land down.
2. To add a speed and power keys so if i click on the power the ship will lift/land faster and if i click the speed the ship will start moving forward fastero r slower. Now the ship is not moving at all it's only move up vertical. Cant move the ship forward.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class MakeObjectFly : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public float AmbientSpeed = 100.0f;
       public float RotationSpeed = 200.0f;

       Rigidbody _rigidbody;

       void Start()
       {
           _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
       }

       void Update ()
       {
           Quaternion AddRot = Quaternion.identity;
           float roll = 0;
           float pitch = 0;
           float yaw = 0;
           roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll") * (Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
           pitch = Input.GetAxis("Pitch") * (Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
           yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * (Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
           AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-pitch, yaw, -roll);
           _rigidbody.rotation *= AddRot;
           Vector3 AddPos = Vector3.forward;
           AddPos = _rigidbody.rotation * AddPos;
           _rigidbody.velocity = AddPos * (Time.deltaTime * AmbientSpeed);
       }
   }
   ```

I have on the space ship RigidBody settings: Mass 0.1 Drag 0 Angular drag 0 Use Gravity unchecked Is Kinematci unchecked Interpolate Interpolate Collision Detection Discrete and Constraints unchecked all Freeze Position and checked all Freeze Rotation.

Mesh Collider: Convex checked.

And Make Object Fly script.

Comment: Well, in general that would be done with some variables like `bool isGrounded`, `float flightSpeed`, `float landingSpeed`. You set these depending on keyboard-input or conditions (for the grounded) and respect them for other input, e.g. disable movement while on ground, and movement,  e.g. incorporate flight speed as factor in your forward movement.

Comment: Why when i mark not to use with // the line: _rigidbody.velocity = AddPos * (Time.deltaTime * AmbientSpeed); when running the game i keep see the Y axis on Position value keep going up. Very slow but still keeping going up. I want to make that the ship will not move up at all and use the bool isGrounded to decide when the ship should move up lift off or landing back.

Comment: It probably gets some velocity somewhere else like if you place it on the ground it might get a little notch from the collision. Maybe enable gravity in that case.

Comment: Ok figured out and the isGrounded now working. Now i need to find out the speed/power part.